# What does the output mean of imaplib.IMAP4_SSL().search in Python?

Tags: python, imaplib

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
typ, accountDetails =m.login(userName, passwd)
m.select("inbox")
resp, data = m.search(None, "(ON {0})".format( time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") ),'(FROM "email")' )
print(resp)
print(data)
```

This gives me the output:

```
OK
[b'6391 6395']
```

So I assume 'OK' means it found an email but I'm not sure what the ' [b '6391 6395'] means. What do those numbers represent?

Comment: those are the uids of the matched emails

Answer (score 0):

imaplib does not really parse responses, so you're getting a fairly raw response from the library.  The `OK` is the overall response to the command, which means that the server understood your request.

Each line of the response is returned as an item in a list.  `SEARCH` only returns one line, so you have a list of one item.  Since imaplib does not do any parsing, you are getting the text of that response in it's original format: a bytes object of space separated numbers, representing Message Sequence Numbers.

You should be able to get a list of MSNs with `msns = data[0].split(b' ')`.

You can then loop over this list to obtain further information, for example:

```
for msn in msns:
  resp, data = m.fetch(msn, '(RFC822)')
```

Comment: (Note, this is not the the most efficient way to fetch multiple messages)